# bundle (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have been trying to install bundle on arch linux while on version 1.9.3 switched using chruby. I thought chruby was the problem and a switched to rbenv but the problem persisted. I could not install gems in version 1.9.3 and then back to chruby but same isssue. Gems just domn't seem to install.

The output from running `bundle` is:

`/opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.5, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.5] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:into_spec'

        from /opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in gem'

        from /home/urbanslug/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin/bundle:22:in'`

My `gem env` output is:

`RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-22 patchlevel 392) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/urbanslug/.gem/ruby/1.9.3
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/urbanslug/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/urbanslug/.gem/ruby/1.9.3
     - /opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org/"]
     - "gem" => "--user-install"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). It just makes installing/maintaining so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install or setup rbenv exactly? rbenv can install and setup different ruby development environment separately, including the gem path.  Assume your git and curl are working, you can use [getrbenv](http://getrbenv.com/) to configure/install rbenv easily.  Or you can install first without default ruby version by:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinsteinorth/getrbenv-installer/master/bin/install.sh | bash -s -- --plugins sstephenson/ruby-build,rkh/rbenv-update`

After source your profile or restart your shell, install ruby and set the default version

`rbenv install 1.9.3-p551
rbenv rehash
rbenv global 1.9.3-p551`

Now your bundle should work for your gems.  You can also consider newer version like 2.2.2 or 2.0.0-p645. Good luck!